# Find a matrix such that $(1,1,1)\in C(A)$ and $N(A)=span(1,1,1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find a matrix such  that $(1,1,1)\in C(A)$ and $N(A)=span(1,1,1,1)$.

From the dimensions, I know that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times4}$, and a column should be $[1~1~1]^T$.

Also, it has to satisfy $A[\alpha~\alpha~\alpha~\alpha]^T=[0~0~0]^T$.

So the matrix would have 3 pivots and one free variable. However, I'm struggling trying to get the coefficients so the nullspace of A is that span, any hints or advice on how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you want $(1,1,1)$ in the column space of A, so write $(1,1,1)$ as the first column and you want $(1,1,1,1)$ in the null space so make sure each row sum adds upto 0$. For example, the following matrix works.

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1& 1&- 3\\
1 & 1& 1&- 3\\
1 & 1& 1&- 3
\end{pmatrix}$
Here,  $A(1,0,0,0)^t= (1,1,1)^t$ and $A(1,1,1,1)^t= (0,0,0)^t$

Comment: Great, I can see it works. But could you explain a bit why each row sums adds up to 0?

Comment: Each row sum should add upto zero because you want $A(1,1,1,1)=0$. Try writing down $A=[a_{ij}]$ and see that the equation precisely means row sum of $A$ should be zero.

Comment: Right, I understand now, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!